# usage of the term "bete noir"

Tags: expressions, word-usage, french

Can "bete noir" refer to something for which one has mild disdain? Ex. 'my bete noir in that movie was the dialogue between Jack and Kate' [that being the exception, overall I liked the film]

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you? What adjectives does it use to qualify the dislike described in the entry for *bete noir*?

Comment: Most dictionaries define it as someone or something which is particularly disliked or dreaded / the bane of one's existence. Very seldom are adjectives used in defining it. Almost always nouns like, *anathema* are cited. I wanted to use it somewhat playfully in a review of a film noir movie where I enjoyed the ambiance of the film but found the storyline disjointed, incredulous and stupid. KarlG confirmed that hyperbolic or ironic usage of the term is reasonable. Hence, my bête noire of this film noir classic is the storyline.

Comment: I walk away thoroughly enriched by the answers and feedback that ensued from the question I posed. It was my first ever encounter with this website which I stumbled upon as I sought clarification for an expression drawn from the Oort cloud of my vocabulary. As I was blissfully unaware of what constitutes on/off-topic, the impounding of my question is not unexpected. If you'd like me to reword it I'm happy to do so. But these cyber bits are probably best relegated for recycling.

Answer (score 4):

A [*bête noire*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%AAte_noire) (note spelling), a "black beast," isn't just a source of mild disgust, but a pet peeve that pushes all your buttons. Of course you can always use the term hyperbolically or ironically, but a casual use to express mere displeasure wouldn't be doing justice to the word.

Comment: "Note spelling" ... in the US, accents are usually not used.

Comment: I was aiming more toward the _noire_, but dictionaries will usually retain the circumflex. Frankly, I'm not even sure French still uses it in this word. There was a spelling reform recently.

Comment: I missed the *noir/noire* error.

Comment: @GEdgar You **have** to spell it with circumflex or it doesn't mean that and wouldn't be pronounced right. It's from a replaced *s* in the original, think *bestial*. Not knowing the gender is also the bug in the *noir/noire* error. Honestly, it's best not to use foreign expressions, especially when you don't know the language. Otherwise people just embarrass themselves by unconsciously mutilating these things; makes a person look uneducated and unaware, doubtless the exact opposite of the effect they're aiming for.

Comment: Some of these expressions are better spoken than written for all of the reasons above.